# Open two Chromes in remote debugging mode and connect to Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to control two different Chrome drivers in remote debugging mode with python simultaneously (Windows 10). Everything works fine when I open the first browser with `chrome.exe –remote-debugging-port=9222 –user-data-dir=C:\myfiles` via terminal and then connect Selenium to it in python:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9222")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

So far so good and the browser works fine. But when I try to replicate this with a different port while the previous browser is still running, the connection doesn't work. The second browser does open but Selenium cannot connect to it. `chrome.exe –remote-debugging-port=1559 –user-data-dir=C:\myfiles`

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:1559")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

It thinks for ~30 seconds and then gives an error:

> WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:1559
> from chrome not reachable

Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initiate new chrome profiles for each port.

1. Create empty folders for new profiles e.g E:\chromeprofile\28180, E:\chromeprofile\28280
2. run start cmd:

start chrome --remote-debugging-port=28180 --user-data-dir=E:\chromeprofile\28180

start chrome --remote-debugging-port=28280 --user-data-dir=E:\chromeprofile\28280

Answer (score 0):

My testing result by far is debug port won't change until you close all the previously opened chrome browser and then run "chrome.exe –remote-debugging-port=1559 –user-data-dir=C:\myfiles" command. So that new port will work. My chrome browser version is v105. Thanks!